# Dell Inspiron 15-5568: Touchpad and Keyboard Issues on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: keyboard, dell, touchpad

Hardware Model- Dell Inc. Inspiron 15-5568 
Processor- Intel® Core™ i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 
OS Name-  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (dualboot)
GNOME Version-  42.9 
Software is upto date

Everything was working fine suddenly touchpad stops responding in sessions and sometimes work after a while or after restart though external mouse is working fine. 
Along this, keyboard also does not work properly.Sometimes some keys automatically pressed, or I cant write the text it gets  erased suddenly.Sometimes it works fine though.